# Reading ASL log file - Python

Tags: python, macos, logfile

I'm trying to read Mac OS ASL log file with Python by using [this asl package](https://asl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). I think the package is successfully installed but I can't import it. Below are the error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/serenasmac1/PycharmProjects/Test2/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asl/__init__.py", line 8, in 
    from ._asl import *
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'asl._asl'
```

As far as I understood, **init**.py is calling a ._asl module but it doesn't exist. Is my understanding correct? How can I fix it?

Also, I've found [this script](https://github.com/cclgroupltd/ccl-asl/blob/master/ccl_asldb.py) which seems can read asl file. I'm trying it in parallel. I've searched a lot but only found this script and the ASL package. I'd really appreciate if anybody can share the knowledge of how to read asl file with Python. Thanks a lot!

Here is the how the package was installed:
[image]

Comment: If you can't import the module, it is not successfully installed. How did you install it?

Comment: @Daniel: I used pip install. When I do pip search asl, I can see the package and it says INSTALLED: 1.0.1 (latest). However, when I run python3 -m asl, it returns "/Users/serenasmac1/PycharmProjects/Test2/venv/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'asl.__main__' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'asl._asl'); 'asl' is a package and cannot be directly executed
". I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: did you install it with pip3 (it might be installed in 2.7)?

Comment: @manandearth. No I did with pip (usually it is installed in 3.5 by default) but I just did pip3, it returned "Requirement already satisfied: asl in ./venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages"

Comment: [This issue was already reported and fixed](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/asl/pull-requests/1/adding-ext_modules-to-metadata-this-is-not/diff), however, because the author of `asl` didn't bother, the fix is still unmerged. You can clone the repo, apply the fix (it's just one line with `ext_modules` to add to `setup.py`) and install from the fixed repo: `pip install path/to/ast/repo`.

Comment: @hoefling this doesn't appear to actually add `._asl` to the `asl` module namespace. Can you confirm your suggestion worked on your machine?

Comment: @RonaldOussoren - any thoughts on this thread?

Comment: @hoefling Thanks a lot for the info and detailed instructions! I couldn't have found this myself.

Comment: @duhaime I just tried it and it worked on my machine, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Serena glad to help a fellow berliner! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the asl package is actually broken. I'd use the `syslog` executable that ships with OSX:

```
from subprocess import check_output

cmd = 'syslog -f /private/var/log/asl/2018.04.03.U501.asl'
log = check_output(cmd.split())
print(log)
```

Comment: @Serena excellent--I love a simple solution. I didn't know about these files, so I'm glad you asked the question. Feel free to click the green checkbox to let others know this solution worked for you!